# Problem with centering view with numpad . Blender 2.83

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I'm new to Blender but currently learning and I have this problem that clicking on an object and then numpad . centers the view on this object but by selecting this object in the outliner without actually clicking on it, the numpad . key doesn't work. So do the other views with the numpad. Even the camera view numpad 0 is like locked and nothing happens unless I actually click on an object.

My preferences are the factory ones, I even tried to edit the key biding but it doesn't change.

In the formation I'm following it seems like it was working in Blender 2.81

If someone has a solution or has the same problem I'll take it gladly.

Comment: The numpad "." key works for different windows, so it depends over which window your mouse is hovering. You can try selecting something in the Outliner and move your mouse back to the 3D View before pressing numpad "." . (If this is indeed your problem you might also like to know it works in the opposite way: If you have a very long Outliner list or an object hidden deep in a hierarchy, you can select an object in the 3D View, move the mouse over the Outliner and press numpad " .")

Comment: Thank you very much and for the tips too! Yes it was an hovering problem. I was just leaving my mouse in the outliner then pressing numpad "." and that's why it wasn't working.